# What is this crystal on my concrete?

Tags: concrete

My concrete has an old unknown spill which appears in the newly warm moist weather to be forming crystals or hairs. It doesn't have direct water on it, and hasn't been damp recently.

[image: white hairy crystal growing out of flat concrete with darkened spill area]

What is the likely cause?

Is this likely to result in damage?

How should I treat the spilled area?

Comment: How can I treat brick efflorescence? [Use vinegar.](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/how-can-i-treat-brick-efflorescence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is Efflorescence.  Harmless, just looks bad.

It's not a spill, just minerals from the concrete crystallizing on the surface of the concrete.  This is very normal and when it is humid, not much can be done about it.  Just wash it off when you notice it.